# Embedded cascaded if-else statements

Tags: microcontroller, audio, frequency, algorithm

I'm designing an MCU based acoustic guitar tuner. I've broken the frequency spectrum from note C2 (65.41 Hz) to note C5 (523.25 Hz) into many sub-bands to give the user an accurate depiction of what note they're plucking. The note letter, number, and an indication of whether they're slightly sharp, slightly flat, or well-tuned will appear on an LCD.

The problem is that I can't see a way to avoid a massive if-else chain to determine in which band the input frequency lies. I've got 66 cases of 'else if ()', and this seems very slow/inefficient/silly to me. I need to figure of what note they've played and get it out to the LCD before the next pulse comes in. At highest frequency, this gives me a little less than 2 ms. Just clocking out 32 bits serially to the LCD driver takes up a decent amount of those 2 ms, so I need to figure out in which band the frequency lies fairly quickly. Can I do anything to improve the software and avoid a ridiculous amount of if-else-statements?

Edit for more information:

I'm programming in C on an AVR ATmega. To associate a frequency with a note, I'm using the formula: frequency = 440 * 2^(x / 12), where x is the number of half-steps away from A4 (440 Hz). An input is well-tuned if it is within +/- 0.25 half-steps from its centre-frequency. It is considered flat if it is less than 0.25 half-steps from centre but greater than 1 half-step from centre (where the half-steps are negative with respect to centre). It is sharp if it is more than 0.25 half-steps from centre but less than 1 half-step from centre (where the half-steps are positive with respect to centre).

For example:

G2 flat = [92.5 Hz, 96.6 Hz]

G2 good = [96.6 Hz, 99.4 Hz]

G2 sharp = [99.4 Hz, 103.8 Hz]

Where G2 centre frequency is 98 Hz.

Comment: There are `switch` statements, too.  But it'd help to have a snippet of your code displayed.

Comment: You probably should state the language and specific MCU, though the language is most likely C. There are many approaches. Have you considered using a table, for example? There are also mathematical approaches that may, depending quite a bit on the details you face, be better than a table. Can you provide more information than you have, which includes at least three adjacent notes and their determinations of band, sharpness, flatness, and well-tuned attributes? It would go a long way in helping you.

Comment: Regarding the musical aspect of this, most tuners break a semitone into 100 cents. My gStrings Android tuner indicates acceptably in tune at +/-12 cents but allows much more accurate tuning. You're going to use +/-50 which will be terrible.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the tip. I'll make the bounds tighter for higher frequencies. At lower frequencies, the spacing is so close, I doubt my frequency-measuring implementation could achieve that kind of accuracy.

Comment: You could convert your 66-long chain into a binary tree 6-7 checks deep.

Comment: You don't really have to clock out the data to the LCD every 2ms. Your eye won't be able to see 500 updates per second anyways, so why constrain your code to it? Just skip 9 out of 10 updates  and your display will still be super snappy.

Comment: FYI, a 16-bit compare/test/branch in AVR is about 6 instruction cycles. So your whole test statement will take about 400 cycles in the worst case. That is about 50uS for an 8MHz chip. Compared with your 2mS update rate, that really doesn't seem like the first place I would look to optimise. If you arrange the if/else statements in a binary tree then that will save you quite a bit, but be careful with any algorithms as you could easily end up worse off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comments, you have a few musical problems with your approach.

[image]

*Figure 1. The [gStrings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.cohortor.gstrings&hl=en_GB) chromatic tuner displays tuning accuracy in cents. Note the large marks around +/-15 cent to indicate the limits of acceptable tuning.*

- Most tuners break a semitone into 100 cents. The gStrings Android tuner, for example, indicates acceptably in tune at +/-12 cents and most of us would try to do much better than that. You're going to use +/-50 cent which will be terrible as it would allow errors up to half a semitone.
- Most good tuners will allow the user to set a deviation from the A-440 standard to allow tuning to a non-tunable instrument (e.g., an old piano) that is slightly flat. This is also useful when playing along with recordings that are slightly above or below standard concert pitch - possibly due to incorrect speed in the recording equipment. You need to incorporate this feature into yours if it is to be useful.

[image]

*Figure 2. Guitar harmonics. Source: [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Music/eguit.html).*

- The guitar string vibrates simultaneously in several modes - full string, half, third, quarter, fifth, etc., giving the harmonics mixed in with the fundemental. Guitarists can "play harmonics" by plucking the string while very lightly touching the string at the half or third, etc., way point along the string. With a bit of practice you can hear that the harmonic was there all the time when the note was played normally. In effect the guitarist is suppressing the fundemental and allowing the harmonics through. Skip through this [guitar harmonics](https://youtube.com/watch?v=mZ6HKrFFM_4) video to see this in action.

The frequency ratio between adjacent semitones on the well-tempered scale is \$ \sqrt[12]{2} \$. If your system has enough computational power you could convert the fundemental frequency to a \$ log_{12} \$ which will linearise the semitone scale into a simple arithmetic sequence.

*Table 1: Note that the difference between log values of adjacent notes is a constant.*

```
Note    Frequency       Log base 12     Diff of logs
A       440             2.4494983453    
A#      466.1637615181  2.4727435908    0.0232452455
B       493.8833012561  2.4959888363    0.0232452455
C       523.2511306012  2.5192340817    0.0232452455
C#      554.3652619537  2.5424793272    0.0232452455
D       587.3295358348  2.5657245727    0.0232452455
D#      622.2539674442  2.5889698181    0.0232452455
E       659.2551138257  2.6122150636    0.0232452455
F       698.456462866   2.6354603091    0.0232452455
F#      739.9888454233  2.6587055546    0.0232452455
G       783.9908719635  2.6819508       0.0232452455
G#      830.6093951599  2.7051960455    0.0232452455
A       880             2.728441291     0.0232452455
```

By subtracting the log of the reference frequency (A = 440 Hz, A = 339 Hz, etc.) the log value will be 0 at the reference frequency.

Note that if you divide the \$ log_{12} \$ value by 0.0232452455 the values will increment by 1 per semitone. Now your note lookup is

- Round to the nearest integer.
- Integer divide by 12 to find the octave number.
- Modulo 12 division to find the note offset into an array [A, Bb, B, C, C#, etc.].

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a numeric value 'x' (a measured frequency) and bands with defined lower-bounds and upper-bounds, and you wish to find which band contains 'x'. This can be thought of as a mathematical feasibility problem in one direction, and many algorithms could be used. I will describe you in this answer how to use a bissection-style search using a bit of pseudo-code to solve your problem.

Enumerate possible bands:

```
enum band_e = {B1, B2, B3 ... Bn};
```

And write up a function like this for example:

```
band_e getBandFromFreq(double x)
```

In the function, describe your bands bounds:

```
const double bands_lb[] = {LB1, LB2, LB3 ... LBn};
const double bands_ub[] = {UB1, UB2, UB3 ... UBn};
```

Now guess a band in which 'x' could be, let's say B3. If both constraints of B3 are satisfied (LB3 <= x <= UB3), then you guessed correctly, and your function can return B3.

If the guess is incorrect, at least one of the constraints will be satisfied (e.g. LB3 <= x, but x > UB3). This will give a direction in which to continue your search (towards LB4 to LBn in this case). Bissection search means repeating the guess at the middle band of this new range. Each progressive "guess and check" (or iteration) will hopefully reduce multilple possible bands still left to be checked.

Hope this helps! Many other search algorithms can be implemented though, pick your poison. Bissection is usually the most intuitive one.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is searching for the interval containing a given value. Unless you can figure a problem-specific way to construct a map function, the fastest search algorithm is [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Consecutive search will spare you from writing those 66 statements (and save a lot in code size), but it will be about as slow.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, you might consider using a switch statement or scanning through an array. Neither will be much faster than a bunch of if statements but they might be easier to maintain.

You haven’t given the specs of your display driver, but redrawing the display every 2 ms is awfully fast. Unless your display driver has no memory (you can’t just write to the display and it’ll persist indefinitely), I’d try to slow that way down, to 100-200ms.

Also, how are you determining the frequency of your input signal?

Comment: Frequency is determined by microphone -> amplifier -> sine-to-square converter -> MCU interrupt. A counter at system clock frequency begins counting and stops counting at the next pulse, then resets and starts counting again immediately. Between pulses, I try to determine the frequency band and output to LCD. The driver has a latch and does not need to be continually refreshed. I just thought it would be a good idea to provide updates as fast as I possibly could.

Comment: @pr871 in that case, do note that your input signal is not going to be a sine wave for most instruments. You may want to consider that your sine-square generator may cause glitches in the presence of harmonics.

Comment: What about an acoustic guitar specifically? I would have thought that a string vibrating around its centre would produce a sine wave.

Comment: @pr871 - does an acoustic guitar sound like it produces pure sine waves ... ? Not really.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://imgur.com/a/tX4G6) waveform from a guitar. See how there is a dip almost to the center in the middle of a peak? That's going to cause a glitch in your comparator for sure.

Comment: A better way, IMO, would be to take the fourier transform of your signal, and find the highest peak in the transformed signal. That directly corresponds to the fundamental frequency, and is how almost every tuner works.

Comment: @pr871: The guitar string vibrates simultaneously in several modes - full string, half, third, quarter, fifth, etc., giving the harmonics mixed in with the fundemental. Guitarists can "play harmonics" by plucking the string while very lightly touching the string at the half or third, etc., way point along the string. With a bit of practice you can hear that the harmonic was there all the time when the note was played normally. In effect the guitarist is suppressing the fundemental and allowing the harmonics through. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZ6HKrFFM_4.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the goal is to select the closest note for a given frequency, and the frequency can essentially be considered a floating point number.

I think one possible solution would be to have a pre-calculated sorted array that contains the geometric mean of adjacent exact note frequencies and then do a binary search to find the point at which you would insert the newly measured frequency in the list.  A frequency between a pair of array elements is associated only with a single note, since it is the range from half way before the note to half way after the note.  Finding the insertion point tells you the closest note.  Note (pun intended) that you can probably scale the frequencies in the array so that they are 16 bit unsigned integers and similarly scale the measured frequency before the search so that you only have to do integer compares.

You can find the insertion point in an ordered list with a binary search in at most ceiling(log2(N)) compares, where N is the number of notes.  For 88 keys you could find it in at most 7 compares.  Google can find you lots of binary search code examples.

The closest note number technically could be specifically calculated by dividing the frequency by 440 and taking the log to the base of the 12th root of 2, but the calculations involved in that would take longer than the search.

Comment: But how do I figure out which array element I'm supposed to access without being back to the original problem?

Comment: After your update, I think I better understand the question.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the frequency of C3 is double that of C3 (one octave up), and so on until C5.  First, I'd fish out which note you're dealing with using modulo (`%`):

```
/* C2 through B2 */
const float note_bases[7] = [65.41, 73.42, 82.41, 87.31, 98.00, 110.00, 123.47];

/* Your method of measuring your fundamental frequency */
f_meas = measure_frequency();

char note_base = find_note_base( f_meas );

/* ... */
char find_note_base ( float f )
{
    float remainder, min_remainder = 100.0;
    char note;

    for( note = 0; note < 7; note++ )
    {
        remainder = f % note_bases[ note ];

        if( remainder < min_remainder ) min_remainder = remainder;
        else break;
    }

    return note;
}
```

Then I'd determine which octave with simple maths:

```
import <math.h>

char oct = (char)round( f_meas / note_bases[ note_base ] );
```

I'd also suggest not updating your screen so fast.  Whenever my tuner changes LED colors in the tens of milliseconds my brain starts hurting.  A change every 100ms or so should do -- you can go down from there if that's too slow.

Answer (score 0):

I can picture a couple of ways to do this that are fast and efficient.

The first is a standard search with some IF..ELSE..THEN but not very many. Say there are 64 notes to check. Take the input value (for example, it matches number 29): Is it bigger or smaller than number 32? Smaller. Is it bigger or smaller than number 16? Bigger. How about number 24? Bigger. Number 28? Bigger. Number 30? Smaller. Done.
    Five or 6 tests depending on the instruction set. Then test the flat/sharp part. This is a binary search and uses powers of two, just like counting in binary. It cuts the search area in half with each step.

There is another way that can be nearly instant if it works out. Use a lookup table. Your input number can be the index into an array (or offset into a lookup table). If you have plenty of PROM/FLASH this is especially easy. Don't bother with trying to window the data, just drop a couple of low order bits. This will "floor" the data you will use as an index. The contents of the table can just be the note you are looking for, like A flat. Or it can be something more useful for your calculations.

Note, you can get little surface mount 8 pin serial flash chips with 16 MBytes for less then $2. So, huge lookup tables are possible. In your case one of those lookups can give the exact answer you want without dropping bits and without calculating in real-time. It can tell you the note and how much it is off. So, there is your way to get basically instant results by pre-computing the data once and putting it in flash.